# dynamically change html control style using c#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I want to make a website where if admin login through `admin.aspx`
I want to add one more navigation in my menu list.
my menu list is made of `<ul>...<li>` i.e html control
so how can I dynamically add the new

in my master page menu 
or else
initially I add the admin menu and apply the `style { visibility:hidden}`
and when the login is successful I want to change it to `{visibility:visible }`

this is My master page code

```
<ul id="ul_myLst" runat="server">
    <li><a href="Testimonials.aspx">Testimonial</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#fakelink">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#fakelink">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Registration.aspx">Registartion</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="OurFaculty.aspx">Our Faculty</a>
    </li>
    <li id="abc" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden">
        <a href="OurFaculty.aspx">Admin</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this is my `Default.aspx` code

```
if (f.pass.Equals(txtpass.Value)) {

    HtmlGenericControl ul = (HtmlGenericControl)(this.Master.FindControl("abc"));
    //ul.Attributes["class"] = "admin-p";
    ul.Style.Remove("visibility");
    ul.Style["visibility"] = "visible";

    Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");

}
```

this code is working fine but when I go back again to `index.aspx` the admin menu get hides automatically

Comment: What are you using for your login feature? The asp.net login control has built in features to make this insanely easy- You set roles for access and then can use the session variables to show/hide various elements in the app

Comment: no i have my own login page i am not using built in login control

Answer (score 2):

From your code, I am guessing that the line:

```
if(f.pass.Equals(txtpass.Value))
```

is some form of saved value on the login process.
If this is the case and you have some hidden input field or something - then every time your page loads () then call a method that sets the Admin menu. Change the "if" code based on what kind of remembered login value you have working on the site. (Session or viewstate or cookie)

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          setAdminMenu();
        }
    }

 private void setAdminMenu()
    {
      if(f.pass.Equals(txtpass.Value))
      {
        abc.Visibility = visible;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use session and check the presence of session value on the top of your master page. while you are going back to the master page, it again checks for the session value and then you can write css code to set the admin menu as visible.

Technically, step by step procedure:

1. create session on second page (default.aspx)
2. check for session value on top of master page: put an if condition, if session value is present write code to show admin menu in it.
3. create a log-out page to invalidate the session.

you can read more about ASP sessions here: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Comment: @Saba Aslam. You are welcome, if my answer is useful you can tick my answer so that others having same problem can easily find proper solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Saba, you're doing it wrong.

I can think of 2 possible simple ways to accomplish that:

**1. Setting the web control `Visible` property**

In the master page code behind (`MasterPage.master.cs`) add this line to the `OnLoad` or `Page_Load` method:

```
var liAdmin  = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("abc");
liAdmin.Visible  = User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

In the `MasterPage.master` add `runat="server"` to your `<li>` tag.

**2. Adding the `<li>` Programmatically**

In the `MasterPage.master` add `runat="server"` to your `<ul>` tag.

And in the master page code behind add to the `OnLoad` or `Page_Load`:

```
if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    var ulMenu  = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("ul_myLst");
    var liAdmin = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    var a = new HtmlAnchor();
    a.HRef = "OurFaculty.aspx";
    a.InnerText = "Admin";
    liAdmin.Controls.Add(a);
    ulMenu.Controls.Add(liAdmin);
}
```